# How to use create-react-app with Windows 7

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

Tried to fire up a new react app yesterday using create-react-app. Unfortunately, when I used the command `npx create-react-app my-app`, it says "Create React App requires Node 14 or higher." However, when I try to update to Node 14 or any later version, it says Windows 8 or higher is required to update. Since I'm on a work PC, it is a slow process to get my computer upgraded to Windows 10 and might affect other software I have on my computer.

I've been trying to understand Webpack and Babel but having a lot of issues that don't pop up with create-react-app. Is there any way to use create-react-app on Windows 7?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Sorry, Windows 7 reached its EOL and we no longer support it. The last Node version tested on Win7 is 13.6.0."

Comment: I know this isn't what you're looking for, but I feel the need to say - don't delay updates more than necessary. The longer you delay the update the harder and more error prone it will be to finally do it.

Comment: Try this:

npx -p node@12 create-react-app

Comment: However I second what @BrianThompson wrote!

Comment: I'd say the only feasible way would be to use virtualbox and create a linux VM and try to use it while you are waiting for the update. Or you could go full cloud mode and use some Desktop As a Service for example amazon workspaces.

Comment: Definitely agree about not putting off necessary updates. Already talked to IT and they are focusing on upgrading the mechanical engineers' equipment before the software engineers. Joakim M, thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it just said create-react-app is not recognized

Answer (score 13):

The current latest release of the create-react-app project is [v5.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v5.0.0) where support for Node 10 & 12 was dropped.

The only solution you have here, other that upgrading to a newer version of Windows and installing Node 14 is to use an older version of create-react-app.

The newest version that supports Node 10 & 12 is [v3.4.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v3.4.0).

You can initialise your project using the older version with this command:

`npx create-react-app@3.4.0 my-app`

Note that this is not the latest version, and therefore is outdated and will not include the latest features of create-react-app.

Comment: Nevermind, this method gets significantly further than if I just run ```npx create-react-app my-app```. It gets as far as installing a bunch of node modules and a package.json. But at the end it still fails and says Node >= version 14 is required. I managed to find a workaround by downloading a zip of Node v14 and dropping the files into the folder which contains my current node installation.

Answer (score 5):

Is you want to Use Node and react Js on Windows 7 32 bit system.Then just install following versions of node and create-react-app.

```
use Node 13.12.0
```

and to create react app use create-react-app version 3.4.0

```
npx create-react-app@3.4.0 my-app
```

this is working without any error and tested till installations
Otherwise consider upgrading your system as well as your software.